# How to format a field (round off decimal places) in JasperReports Server professional edition?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *JR Server professional edition*. I am creating a report in which i am getting table_id field with 2 decimal places. I want to see the table_id as it is i.e with in the integer format no decimal places.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using iReport click the table_id text field, go to the **Properties** banner on the right and go to the **Pattern** property. Click the "..." button and when the **Pattern** window pops up, reduce the **Decimal places** property from 2 to 0.

If you are working in XML, add the **pattern** parameter to the **textField** property like this:

```
<textField pattern="###0">
```